# Random Character Generator Java

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, object, ascii

I need to make a `keyMaker` function that randomly generates a string which is exactly 23 characters long. They need to be lower case letters and grouped into clusters of five with a hyphen between each set of five. (ex. fdior-fhwkd-ruwka-qozsm).

I need to use the string function that converts the character number into the character (a=97,z=122...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you mean Java or JavaScript? The two are completely different. Also, [what have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am tempted to down vote. Please post what you have attempted so far?

Comment: _"I need to use the string function that converts the character number into the character"_ - Not if you use an array of allowable characters and randomly select from that array. You did use the "arrays" tag on your question...

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();

public static String makeRandomString() {
    char nextChar;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        // lowercase characters go from 97 to 122
        nextChar = (char) (rnd.nextInt(26) + 97);
        sb.append(nextChar);
        if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0 && i != 19) sb.append('-');
    }

    return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: Upvoting However,this is spoon feeding.I was expecting @wdebvrd to post his attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in Javascript:

```
function generateKeyString() {
    var key = "", random;
    var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (i !== 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
            key += "-";
        }
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
        key += letters.charAt(random);
    }
    return(key);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9mFb5/

Comment: I'd be interested to know what's faster, this implementation or something that uses `var chr = String.fromCharCode(97 + n);` where `n` is a random number. But I don't have a javascript development environment set up

Comment: @durron597 you don't need a JS environment "set up": http://jsfiddle.net – or even better for benchmarking, http://jsperf.com

Comment: @durron597 - You don't even need an internet connection to test performance on something like this: any browser plus any text editor can get the job done...

Comment: @durron597 - jsperf would answer the performance question (probably not a big difference between number to string conversion vs. string index - as neither is particularly time consuming), but I often do it this way because you can more easily modify the allowed character set.

Comment: I know you don't need an "environment" for javascript, it was more about getting a benchmark I trust